# Read and modify data from kendo wrapper spreadsheet (kendo-spreadsheet-vue-wrapper)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, telerik

I am able to setup the spreadsheet with an active sheet containing 5 columns and a first row (header). I have a localdatasource with example data, which are perfeclty shown in the sheet. But when i want to read the values that i manually entered, i get stuck. My datasource object doesn't update. I tried to set the spreadsheet component to a ref, to possibly get the component. But that also didnt work.
The main goal is that a user can edit or paste data, and that i can save the data entered.

Here's my code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  Spreadsheet,
  SpreadsheetSheet,
  SpreadsheetInstaller
} from '@progress/kendo-spreadsheet-vue-wrapper'
import '@progress/kendo-ui'
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

// let spreadsheet = ref<Spreadsheet>()

// function assignWidget(el: any) {
//   nextTick(() => {
//     spreadsheet.value = el
//   })
// }

const toolbar = {
  home: false,
  insert: false,
  data: false
}

const header = [
  {
    height: 25,
    cells: [
      {
        value: 'ProductID',
        background: 'rgb(167,214,255)',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'rgb(0,62,117)'
      },
      {
        value: 'ProductName',
        background: 'rgb(167,214,255)',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'rgb(0,62,117)'
      },
      {
        value: 'UnitPrice',
        background: 'rgb(167,214,255)',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'rgb(0,62,117)'
      },
      {
        value: 'UnitsInStock',
        background: 'rgb(167,214,255)',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'rgb(0,62,117)'
      },
      {
        value: 'Discontinued',
        background: 'rgb(167,214,255)',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'rgb(0,62,117)'
      }
    ]
  }
]

function validate() {
  // log datasource here
  console.log(datasource)
}

let datasource = ref([
  {
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: 'Chai',
    UnitPrice: 18,
    UnitsInStock: 39,
    Discontinued: false
  },
  {
    ProductID: 2,
    ProductName: 'Chang',
    UnitPrice: 17,
    UnitsInStock: 40,
    Discontinued: false
  },
  {
    ProductID: 3,
    ProductName: 'Aniseed Syrup',
    UnitPrice: 10,
    UnitsInStock: 13,
    Discontinued: false
  },
  {
    ProductID: 4,
    ProductName: 'Chef Anton',
    UnitPrice: 22,
    UnitsInStock: 53,
    Discontinued: false
  },
  {
    ProductID: 5,
    ProductName: 'Chef Gumbo Mix',
    UnitPrice: 21.35,
    UnitsInStock: 0,
    Discontinued: true
  },
  {
    ProductID: 6,
    ProductName: 'Boysenberry Spread',
    UnitPrice: 25,
    UnitsInStock: 120,
    Discontinued: false
  }
])
</script>

<template>
  <div class="view">
    <h2>Pin Excel Upload</h2>
    <spreadsheet
      :columns="5"
      :column-width="200"
      active-sheet="PINUpload"
      pdf-proxy-URL="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
      excel-proxy-URL="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
      :toolbar="toolbar"
      ref="spreadsheet"
      style="width: 100%"
    >
      <spreadsheet-sheet
        name="PINUpload"
        :rows="header"
        :data-source="datasource"
      ></spreadsheet-sheet>
    </spreadsheet>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="validate()">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check" />
      Validate
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
<style>
@import '@progress/kendo-ui/css/web/default-blue.css';
</style>
```

I tried to solve this to make the ref on Spreadsheet a :ref to a function assignWidget() (see comment). By this way, i thought i could resolve the component and read it's data from the sheet(s).